# Google Drive SDK last version

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I am a beginner programmer on C# and Asp.net MVC
I install in my project last google drive sdk from the nuget.
I need to download/upload files from only **my** google drive account storage
https://developers.google.com/drive/web/auth/web-server#authenticate_the_user - this writes how to Authenticate the user, its simply.
but i wont to upload/download/create/delete... files from only **my** google drive account storage not user owner.
How to provide the access to my account other user?
help me please

Answer (score 1):

Your two options are to use a "service account", or to embed a refresh token for you account in your server app and use that to request an access token. For the second option you will need to do a one-time authorization which you can do using the Oauth playground.

Comment: In your browser, type ctrl-l. Then enter
"google oauth service account" (without the quotes), and press the Enter key.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#service_account and how using this upload file to acc user1@gmail.com from user2@gmail.com